# Definition com.revmob.airextension:Revmob could not be found.

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, revmob

I am using Flash cs5 to make iOS App I have referenced Revmob.ane in the File->Actionscript settings->Library path and then imported the revmob extension in my Game.as by

```
import com.revmob.airextension.Revmob
```

but still Game.as could not find Revmob extension how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you imported the ane file?

Answer (score 0):

Man I had the same problem.I contacted Revmob tech support:Since you can't test revmob on your PC and therefore you get that error.So,just publish your application and test it on a mobile device-everything's supposed to work fine)